# The AuthorizeAttribute doesn't effect authorization using JWT in dotnet core webapi 2.1 application

Tags: c#, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, netcoreapp2.1

I'm trying to use JWT in a core webapi application. Here is my `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddDbContextPool("Bla Bla");
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>("Bla Bla");

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
services.AddAuthentication(o => {
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(c => {
    c.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    c.SaveToken = true;
    c.TokenValidationParameters = 
        new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
});

services.AddRouting("Bla Bla");
services.AddMvcCore("Bla Bla").AddControllersAsServices();
```

And this is `Startup.Configure()` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(rb => 
    { rb.MapRoute("api_default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"); });
```

Anyway, I have created a protect action to test (which I'm expecting to return an `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` error):

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async Task<object> Info() {
        return "Authorized!";
    }
}
```

But its getting authorized and responsing "Authorized!" all the time. It seems the `Authorize` attribute doesn't effect at all. Am I missing something?

P.S. I have tried both `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` attribute.

P.S.2 I have tried extending the controller from both `ControllerBase` and `Controller`.

P.S.3 I have tried without clearing default claims (removed this line `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`).

None of them worked.

**Framework and packages info:**

- Target Framework: `netcoreapp2.1`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore` Version = `2.1.6`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` Version = `2.1.2`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` Version = `2.1.6`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` Version = `2.1.3`

**UPDATE:**

According to [@sellotape's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465832/the-authorizeattribute-doesnt-effect-authorization-using-jwt-in-dotnet-core-web?noredirect=1#comment93802532_53465832), I have returned the `User` object from the action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<object> Info() {
    return User;
}
```

And here is the output JSON:

```
{
    "identities": [
        {
            "isAuthenticated": false,
            "claims": [],
            "roleClaimType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
            "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
        }
    ],
    "identity": {
        "isAuthenticated": false,
        "claims": [],
        "roleClaimType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
        "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
    },
    "claims": []
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that controller action and examine the user claims and identities to see where the authenticated Identity is coming from. That should give some clues...

Comment: @sellotape nothing important came out. Claims and identities are empty. See the update to see the complete `User` object.

Comment: I think you're missing `services.AddAuthorization();` in `ConfigureServices()`...

Comment: @sellotape I added `services.AddAuthorization()` but nothing changed ):

Comment: Ah I see you're using `.AddMvcCore()` rather than `.AddMvc()`; you need to add `.AddAuthorization()` to _that_, rather than just general services. So e.g. `.AddMvcCore().AddAuthorization()`.

Comment: @sellotape yes  I figure it out. Thanks to consultant. If you want, post your answer (Ill delete my own) so I can accept that.

Comment: thanks; I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that when you use `.AddMvcCore()`, you're only wiring up a small part of what you get when you use `.AddMvc()` instead.  For many solutions, it's simpler to just use the latter, as you then automatically get the following added and ready to use [[source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)]:

- API Explorer
- Authorization
- Views
- Razor View Engine
- Razor Pages
- JSON Formatters
- CORS
- (a few others)

If you prefer to only add what you absolutely need, you can elect to use `.AddMvcCore()` instead, but then you need to explicitly add the MVC services you require; e.g. in this case (Authorization), you would need to

```
services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization();
```

Note how `.AddAuthorization()` here is being applied to the result of `services.AddMvcCore()`, which is an `IMvcBuilder`, *not* to `services`, which is an `IServiceCollection`.